# How can I access parameter value from URL in the controller?

Tags: php, phalcon, url-parameters

I need some information about parameter passing in the phalcon framework

example URL : `http://localhost/project/vehicle/new/vinno/1323123`

```
vehicleController{
    newAction {
        //get the value of vinno

        // want to send parameter to view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dumping the dispatcher parameters.

```
print_r($this->dispatcher->getParams());
```

The above will give you the complete parameters array according to your router definition. More info about dispatcher in **[the docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Dispatcher.html)**.

To get a specific parameter value you can use `getParam()` method.

```
print_r($this->dispatcher->getParam('your_param_name'));
```

Comment: can we mention the parameter name to get its value .?

Answer (score 2):

Use route parameter. And use `$this->view->setVar`